# receiving scroll-events on GtkToolButtons

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Is there a way to catch scroll events on `GtkToolButton` widgets ? From what I tried, I can only catch these using a regular button packed in a generic `GtkToolItem`.

Here is a minimal example showing the difference :

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>

gboolean click_cb(
    GtkWidget* widget, 
    GdkEvent* ev, 
    gpointer window
    )
{
   gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(window))  ;
   return TRUE ;
}

gboolean scroll_cb(
    GtkWidget* widget, 
    GdkEventScroll* ev, 
    gpointer user_data
    )
{
    printf("scrolled %p\n", (void*) widget) ;
    return FALSE ;
}

void activate_cb(
    GtkApplication* app,
    gpointer        user_data
    )
{
  /* create the window */
  GtkWidget* window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Scroll Test");
  printf("window is at %p\n", (void*) window) ;

  /* create a toolbar */
  GtkWidget* toolbar = gtk_toolbar_new() ;
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), toolbar) ;
  printf("toolbar is at %p\n", (void*) toolbar) ;

  /* create a tool button */
  GtkToolItem* tool_button = gtk_tool_button_new(NULL, NULL) ;
  gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), tool_button, -1) ;
  printf("tool button is at %p\n", (void*) tool_button) ;

  /* create an icon image */
  GtkWidget* button_icon = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name(
      "edit-copy", 
      GTK_ICON_SIZE_LARGE_TOOLBAR
      ) ;
  gtk_tool_button_set_icon_widget(GTK_TOOL_BUTTON(tool_button), button_icon) ;

  /* create a generic toolbar item */
  GtkToolItem* generic_item = gtk_tool_item_new() ;
  gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), generic_item, -1) ;

  /* create a button */
  GtkWidget* button = gtk_button_new() ;
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(generic_item), button) ;
  printf("generic button is at %p\n", (void*) button) ;

  /* create an icon image */
  GtkWidget* generic_icon = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name(
      "edit-paste", 
      GTK_ICON_SIZE_LARGE_TOOLBAR
      ) ;
  gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(button), generic_icon) ;


  /* signals */
  gtk_widget_add_events(GTK_WIDGET(tool_button), GDK_SCROLL_MASK);
  g_signal_connect(
      tool_button,
      "scroll-event",
      G_CALLBACK(scroll_cb),
      NULL
      ) ;

  gtk_widget_add_events(GTK_WIDGET(button), GDK_SCROLL_MASK);
  g_signal_connect(
      button,
      "scroll-event",
      G_CALLBACK(scroll_cb),
      NULL
      ) ;

  gtk_widget_add_events(GTK_WIDGET(toolbar), GDK_SCROLL_MASK);
  g_signal_connect(
      toolbar,
      "scroll-event",
      G_CALLBACK(scroll_cb),
      NULL
      ) ;

  gtk_widget_add_events(GTK_WIDGET(window), GDK_SCROLL_MASK);
  g_signal_connect(
      window,
      "scroll-event",
      G_CALLBACK(scroll_cb),
      NULL
      ) ;

  /* show all the elements */
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new (
        "org.gtk.scroll_test",
        G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE
        ) ;
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate_cb), NULL);
    g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), 0, NULL) ;

    return 0;
}
```

and a Makefile to compile it if you saved the above file as `scroll_toolbar.c` :

```
CC = gcc

SOURCES = scroll_toolbar.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)
LDFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)

scroll_toolbar: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJECTS) : %.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $? -o $@
```

For a sample output, the program starts with :

```
window is at 0x13f8260
toolbar is at 0x149a1e0
tool button is at 0x15981e0
generic button is at 0x1599370
```

then when I scroll the `GtkToolButton` I get :

```
scrolled 0x13f8260
scrolled 0x13f8260
```

meaning that only the window receives the event, but on the other button :

```
scrolled 0x13f8260
scrolled 0x1599370
scrolled 0x149a1e0
scrolled 0x13f8260
```

showing that now both the toolbar and the button receive the event.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to receive a scoll event on a tool button widget, nor am I even sure if that'd work (it might, though). Have you tried simply handling the signal with a separate callback from the toolbutton, and have the handler return true to stop the event?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem what do you mean by a separate callback from the toolbutton ? Do you mean handling the signal in the window ? The idea is that when the button is scrolled, its icon is changed and related data is updated. You can think of it as a drawing application, which can draw various shapes, each of which can have several rotations. I would like to use one button per shape, and scroll the button to select its rotation.

Comment: What I meant was that, AFAIK [scroll events](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkToolButton.html) aren't supported by the GtkToolButton widget, but you can double-check that by hooking the signal up with a custom callback that stops the event... PS: `printf("scrolled %p\n", widget) ;` should be `printf("scrolled %p\n", (void *)widget) ;` -> printing pointer values is one of the few cases where you actually need to cast the pointer

Comment: Just for completeness on the required void cast: _"(C11, 7.21.6.1p8 Formatted input/output functions) The argument shall be a pointer to void."_ mainly because not all pointers are guaranteed to be of the same size (they generally are (function pointers asside), but it's not guaranteed)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem about the `(void*)` thing, I'll fix it, thanks. About the callback, I thought my code was already trying to hook a callback on the signal for the widget. The GtkToolButton even prevents the ToolBar from receiving the event, which the regular button does not.